# How to set a specific label for a checkout operation in StarTeam?

Tags: label, checkout, starteam

I use multiple buildboxes which have StarTeam in them. I see a peculiar thing: all buildboxes differ in checkout label. Is there any specific setting to be done so that I can maintain a uniform default checkout label so that I don't need to change the desired label from the drop down each time for all buildboxes?

Comment: Your **CAPS LOCK** key appears to be broken.

Comment: Did you spill coffee on your keyboard?

Comment: @  Paul R > oops .. jus mow I noticed !! Thanks :D

Comment: I don't quite get the question - when you go to the checkout dialog, the ordering of the labels is different from machine to machine?  In pre-2005R2 clients, the labels would be in order of creation time.  In 2005R2 and later clients, they should be in alphabetical order.  I think this has to do with the java version used, actually, as we had some weird dialog differences on identical client installs with different java installs.

Comment: @ Jeremy Murray > Thanks for the insightful response. As u said,In 2005R2 and later clients, they should be in alphabetical order which I found by some trial & error methods !! :)

Comment: @Jeremy Murray:  Please place your comment as an answer so it can be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

**[Jeremy Murray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88834/jeremy-murray)** said:

I don't quite get the question - when you go to the checkout dialog,
the ordering of the labels is different from machine to machine?

In pre-2005R2 clients, the labels would be in order of creation time.
In 2005R2 and later clients, they should be in alphabetical order.

I think this has to do with the java version used, actually,
as we had some weird dialog differences on identical client installs with different java installs.